# Clear value from input field when select value from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this drop down list:

```
<select name="group_psoft" id="group_psoft">
    <option value="0" selected="selected" title="0">---select---</option>
    <option value="100" title="100">100</option>
    <option value="200" title="200">200</option>
    <option value="300" title="300">300</option>
</select>
```

and one input field:

```
<input id="name" value="">
```

How do I clear out the value of the "name" input when I change value in the dropdown list?

Kind regards

Comment: It's been a while since I used jQuery, you should be able to add an onChange handler to the select element. Then whenever it gets select, `$('#name').val()` to change the input value

Comment: `$('#group_psoft').change(function() {$('#name').val('')});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `change()` function in jquery which triggers when you change the `select` like this

[Read Here about .change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

```js
$('#group_psoft').change(function() {$('#name').val('')});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="group_psoft" id="group_psoft">
<option value="0" selected="selected"title="0">---select---</option>
<option value="100" title="100">100</option>
<option value="200" title="200">200</option>
<option value="300" title="300">300</option>
</select>
<input id="name" value="Initial Value">
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `change` event of the list and then update the input on each occurrence of change.

```js
$('#group_psoft').change(function() {
  // Set the input's value to the current value of the list
  $('#name').val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="group_psoft" id="group_psoft">
<option value="0" selected="selected"title="0">---select---</option>
<option value="100" title="100">100</option>
<option value="200" title="200">200</option>
<option value="300" title="300">300</option>
</select>
<input id="name" value="Initial Value">
```

Answer (score 0):

This will clear the input field when the dropdown selection changes:

```js
$("#group_psoft").on("change", function(){
  $("#name").val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="group_psoft" id="group_psoft">
<option value="0" selected="selected"title="0">---select---</option>
<option value="100" title="100">100</option>
<option value="200" title="200">200</option>
<option value="300" title="300">300</option>
</select>

<input id="name" value="">
```